# add hyperlink with images by button or Drag and save current state

Tags: javascript, html

```
<style>
    .grid {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  
    .grid-item {
      width: 50%;
    }
  
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
      .grid-item {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
  
    a {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
    }
  
    input[type="text"] {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item"><a href="https://example.com"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><a href="https://example.com"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><a href="https://example.com"><img src="image3.jpg" /></a></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><a href="https://example.com"><img src="image4.jpg" /></a></div>
  </div>
  
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter image URL" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter hyperlink URL" />
    <button type="submit">Add item</button>
  </form>
  
  <script>
    var grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
    var gridItems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
  
    // Load the saved grid state from local storage
    var gridState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gridState'));
    if (gridState) {
      for (var i = 0; i < gridState.length; i++) {
        var gridItem = document.createElement('div');
        gridItem.classList.add('grid-item');
        gridItem.innerHTML = '<a href="' + gridState[i].hyperlinkUrl + '"><img src="' + gridState[i].imageUrl + '" /></a>';
        grid.appendChild(gridItem);
      }
    }
  
    for (var i = 0; i < gridItems.length; i++) {
      gridItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        window.location.href = this.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');
      });
    }
  
    form.addEventListener
    
  
  ('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        var imageUrl = this.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
        var hyperlinkUrl = this.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
    
        var gridItem = document.createElement('div');
        gridItem.classList.add('grid-item');
        gridItem.innerHTML = '<a href="' + hyperlinkUrl + '"><img src="' + imageUrl + '" /></a>';
        grid.appendChild(gridItem);
    
        // Save the grid state to local storage
        var gridState = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < gridItems.length; i++) {
          var imageUrl = gridItems[i].querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');
          var hyperlinkUrl = gridItems[i].querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');
          gridState.push({
            imageUrl: imageUrl,
            hyperlinkUrl: hyperlinkUrl
          });
        }
        localStorage.setItem('gridState', JSON.stringify(gridState));
      });
    </script>
```

1.This is the full code I don't know why It isn't functional
2. Is there alternative way to save and change code itself? rather than use local storage?

I want functional code
Please help me, I am wandering for more than 24hours now

Comment: In submit event handler get `imageUrl` `hyperlinkUrl` values using `getElementById` query selector after adding id's in input tags of the form.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to take two inputs image's source link and the hyper link it redirects to and store these inputted values and get them when user visits site again.

**1.** You code was fine just that you were not getting values from those input fields. You can change.

```js
var imageUrl = this.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
var hyperlinkUrl = this.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
```

to this (and add respective ids in their input tags)

```js
var imageUrl = document.getElementById('image_url').value;
var hyperlinkUrl = document.getElementById('link').value;
```

```html
<input id="image_url" type="text" placeholder="Enter image URL" />
<input id="link" type="text" placeholder="Enter hyperlink URL" />
```

See this my version of code here: https://jsfiddle.net/gktazfjw/

```js
var grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
var gridItems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
var form = document.querySelector('form');

var tempLink = "https://robohash.org/"

// Load the saved grid state from local storage
var gridState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gridState'));
if (gridState) {
  for (var i = 0; i < gridState.length; i++) {
    var gridItem = document.createElement('div');
    gridItem.classList.add('grid-item');
    gridItem.innerHTML = '<a target="_blank" href="' + gridState[i].hyperlinkUrl + '"><img src="' + gridState[i].imageUrl + '" /></a>';
    grid.appendChild(gridItem);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < gridItems.length; i++) {
  gridItems[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    window.location.href = this.querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');
  });
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var imageUrl = document.getElementById('image_url').value;
  var hyperlinkUrl = document.getElementById('link').value;

  alert(imageUrl + ": " + hyperlinkUrl)

  var gridItem = document.createElement('div');
  gridItem.classList.add('grid-item');
  gridItem.innerHTML = '<a href="' + hyperlinkUrl + '"><img src="' + tempLink + imageUrl + '" /></a>';
  grid.appendChild(gridItem);

  // Save the grid state to local storage
  var gridState = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < gridItems.length; i++) {
    var imageUrl = gridItems[i].querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');
    var hyperlinkUrl = gridItems[i].querySelector('a').getAttribute('href');
    gridState.push({
      imageUrl: imageUrl,
      hyperlinkUrl: hyperlinkUrl
    });
  }
  localStorage.setItem('gridState', JSON.stringify(gridState));
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

img {
  width: 30%;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div target="_blank" class="grid-item">
    <a href="https://example.com">

      <img src="https://robohash.org/image1" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div target="_blank" class="grid-item">
    <a href="https://example.com">
      <img src="https://robohash.org/image2" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div target="_blank" class="grid-item">
    <a href="https://example.com">
      <img src="https://robohash.org/image3" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div target="_blank" class="grid-item">
    <a href="https://example.com">
      <img src="https://robohash.org/image4" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<form>
  <input id="image_url" type="text" placeholder="Enter image URL" />
  <input id="link" type="text" placeholder="Enter hyperlink URL" />
  <button type="submit">Add item</button>
</form>
```

**2.** Much better way is to store data in some kind of free cloud database like mongoDB, firebase, etc.
Local storage can be cleared by the user and is limited by the amount of data we can store, but is perfectly fine if it's just for practice , etc and you don't want to use your project for professional things.

But the thing is if you start using some database with your website then you will have to implement authentication logic too, to get only the desired data of any user.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!
If I can have additional question,
How can I link with mongoDB Or firebase
Is it not done by just 1File of code?

Comment: You would need some kind of backend to link mongoDB and stuff, I usually make it using node.js (but there are ton of other languages too for it), after that its just 3..4 lines of code. I recommend you to check out some tutorial on it and visit `mongoDB`, `firebase` official docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageUrl = this.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
var hyperlinkUrl = this.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value
```

You can simply add it by using this code